# Angular - produce Flask-compatible mimetype

Tags: angular, flask

I've been trying to establish a GET-based request from Angular to Flask. it seems I can create requests without any payload normally, however, the problem arises when I'm trying to pass `params`. E.g.,

```
this.http.get(endpointUrl, {params: params})
```

In the backend, I'm ready the response via Flask's `flask_request.get_json()` call. It seems that the input arguments are not None, however, nothing gets parsed. I also tried setting

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'Content-Type: application/json'});
this.http.get(endpointUrl, {params: params, headers: headers})
```

The result is the same. When trying to get `input_arguments = flask_request.get_json()`, it appears to be an empty object.

Could you please help?

EDIT:

The following works flawlessly:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"p1":"v1, "p2":"v2"}' $SOMEENDPOINT/some_api;
```

Is it possible not all arguments are considered as strings or something?

Comment: Can you share the params?

Comment: The '{"p1":"v1, "p2":"v2"}' suffices to replicate the issue

Comment: How do you initialise them? Do you see them on the network tab of the console?

Comment: Yes, the request gets through, however the payload is not there. Was able to solve it by using a generic POST request, still not sure what the reason for this was - posting this as a temporal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to make it work flawlessly using a POST request (i.e. `http.post(url, dictPayload)`) which does not cause any problems at any point.